# How unique are Quarternions and what about the sign?

Tags: robotic-arm, orientation, frame

I want to track a robot's orientation in space and wanted to choose quaternions for their many advantages.

However I have a few questions that I haven't found to be solved anywhere. [The method I use to get quaternions from a rotation matrix is the one by Bar-Itzhack (2000)](https://arc.aiaa.org/doi/abs/10.2514/2.4654). I want to use the "version 3" method always whether or not the rotation matrix is imprecise since the method for precise matrix (version 1) also involves almost the same computational effort (contructing some matrix and getting eigen*)and this way it is more robust if my matrix happens to be imprecise. My questions regarding quaternions are the following:

1. How unique are they when tracking in 3D space? Can I track the rotations of the tool frame without worrying about going through discontinuities in space? (E.g. like with axis-angle representation when the angle gets close to 0° or 180° and even is undefined for those) And no arbitrary outcomes.
2. In the method mentioned above a special matrix is constructed from the rotation matrix and then the eigenvector of the highest eigenvalue is used as the resulting quaternion. I wanted to confirm the correctness with the following test. However the resulting fixed-angle is often negative. So I started to just negate the quaternion but I suspect that there may be cases where this is wrong, so what is the method to determine the sign? This is my verification method:

   1. Get rotation matrix of a fixed rotation around an axis (e.g. +42° about x)
   2. From this rotation, apply the linked method above (version 3) to get the quaternion.
   3. Get a rotation matrix from the quaternion back (method used by Craig)
   4. And finally I convert the rotation matrix back into fixed angle representation and see if the angle is the same.

Any help would be much appreciated.

On this project I am not using ROS, everything is self-build.

Comment: Quaternions are unique. However, Rotation Matrices are not. Therfore expect discontinuities when converting back to a rotaton matrix at step 3 and 4. Depending on which method you use for conversion and how much did your frame move "in the quaternion form" you might get completely different angles back.

Comment: @50k4 Thank you for your comment! But rotation matrices are unique. E.g. see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105264/3d-rotation-matrix-uniqueness

Comment: @Chuck, I posted it as an answer, however I do not think I touched on all question points, that is the reason I posted in as a comment

Comment: @ruffy Yes, it seems that the matrix itself is uneque. I might be wrong and the problems will only appear at step 4 not at step 3.

Comment: Can you please post the code and test case that you're using? I can see the paper you linked that shows the *method*, but how are *you* calculating the eigenvalues and eigenvectors? What is Craig's method and how are *you* implementing it? What method are are you using to get to the fixed angle representation and how did *you* implement it? There are tons of places to go wrong, and it would be much faster to review the work that you've already done than to leave the rest of the site to speculate where it is *possible* to go wrong. Also, FYI, $q = -q$ but otherwise quaternions are unique.

Comment: Yes I know, that is what I commented in the now deleted answer of 50k4. I am basically using everything's Craig, from his book (a very common resource for the fundamentals of robotics) or from the handbook of robotics although not in this case. Everything else works as expected, my real question is/was how to determine deterministically which quaternion to choose so that the mapping from rotation matrix to quaternion is always the

Comment: same. From the paper, it seems that it is recommended to use always the quaternion which last scalar value is positive (so to negate a quaternion if that is not the case). But it is stated in a complicated way and I am not too sure if that is right. It seems that a thorough discussion on all possible representations is really lacking in robotics.